# Showing different properties of a connected component $G_0$ of an identity in a Lie group $G$.

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Let $G_0$ is a connected component of a Lie group $G$. I want to show the following:

1. $G_0$ is a normal Lie subgroup of $G$.
2. Other connected components of $G$ are cosets with respect to $G$.
3. The quotient group $G/G_0$ is discrete.

I am not going to provide full details in my arguments, but I want to check my ideas and if I am on the right track .

$(1)$ For the first one, I want to show that $G_0$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. First, let's show that $G_0$ is a subgroup of $G$. It's enough to show that it is closed under a multiplication and an inverse map. Indeed, since the multiplication map
$$m|_{G_0\times G_0}:G_0\times G_0\to G$$
is smooth, so it's image is connected as $G_0\times G_0$ is connected. Since $m(e,e)=e$, then we can see that $G_0$ is closed under a multiplication map. The same argument works for the second map. Therefore, $G_0$ is a subgroup of $G$.

$(1)$ To show that $G_0$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, it's enough to observe that the map
$$s:G\to G$$
which is given by $s(h)=ghg^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism which permutes the connected components of $G$. Since $s(e)=e$, i.e. it preserves $G_0$, then $G_0$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

$(2)$ We can see that $G=\cup_{h\in G}G_h$ is a disjoint union of connected components $G_h$. To show that any connected component is a coset of $G_0$, we need to show that $G_h=hG_0$ which follows from the fact that $m(h,-)$ send $G_0$ to $G_h$.

$(3)$ According to $(2)$, $G/G_0$ is going to be the disjoint union of the connected components where each connected component is an equivalence class. Since $G_h$ was open and closed in $G$, then the image of $G_h$  is also going to be open and closed.
Therefore, $G/G_0$ has discrete topology.